# How can insert resurce string file in appcelerator alloy

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-mobile, appcelerator-alloy

I want to build my appcelerator application with multi-language.

So I have created one string.xml file and an "en" folder under i18n.

In my controller.js to get the text from this file, I use the following:

```
L(lang+"login_title")
```

But when I try to build my application all folders and files under i18n folder are automatically deleted.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alloy 1.8 relocates i18n folder into app please read this post: [relocates-i18n](http://www.appcelerator.com/blog/2016/03/alloy-1-8-relocates-i18n-and-platform-directories/)